# Gathering statistics in Mac Dictation

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Is there any way to log the use of / gather statistics in [Mac Dictation](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5449), such as the following:

- Use of commands (e.g. log `command name, timestamp`)
- Use of words (e.g. log `wordl, timestamp`)

?

Comment: I don't use the feature myself, but maybe the Console (located in `Applications -> Utilities`) logs these commands? Try the following: Open the Console, go to All Messages, start Dictation, use a command or word, see if it gets logged in the Console.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.